# LESS keeps giving me SyntaxError

Tags: less

I use LESS with npm and I keep track of what it is happening through command prompt. I keep getting this error with tells me that **SyntaxError: media definitions require block statements after any features in ...**

Check out the image

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro|Source+Sans+Pro:400,700,900');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,500,700,900');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700,900');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300');
@montserrat: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
@linkFFam: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
@oswald: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
@headFootBg: #1e1e1e;
@linkColor: #f3f3f3;
@acccentColor: #fff200;


@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    /* or iPad Air 2 on landscape mode */
    section#hero {
        .title { margin-top: 40px; text-align: center; } 
    section#about {
        article {
            h1 { margin-top: 50px; }
            img { padding-top: 50px; }
            p { width: 50%; margin-top: 50px; }
            .down_arrow { margin: 150px auto 0 auto; }
        }
    }
    section#menu { img { max-width: 70%; } }
    footer.container {
        img.knife { margin-top: -105px; }
        .hide { display: none; }
        footer { ul.foot_nav { margin-right: -10px; } }
    }

}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    /* for iPad on portrait mode */
    section#hero { .title { margin-top: 140px; } }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 736px) and (min-width: 414px) and (orientation: landscape) {
    /* for iPhone+ landscape mode */
    section#top_header {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

[image: the error message i get]

Comment: Balance your curly brackets (in this case you're missing the closing brackets for `section#hero`). Get to use some less random formatting to minimize such errors in the future (in particular always intend a new line after `{`).

Comment: Also (aside of above) never use redundant nesting like `section#menu { img { max-width: 70%}}` - it's just ridiculous. Should be `section#menu img { max-width: 70%} ` instead.